# Can I add different image to each items(depending on the condition) in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am populating the list of neighboring devices in the local LAN (which includes android, windows ,Linux etc. devices) in a `ListView`.

I am able to populate the devices in list but I want to append an icon preceding the  item (Like an android symbol if it is an android device and so on ).
I could only add a same icon for all the items but not depending on the condition.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Create a class extending BaseAdapter.

2- Create a template layout xml file for each item of list.

3- inside getView method of your adapter, populate image view with custom drawable.

Look at this link: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html